# Applying metatag to single page

Tags: html, mobile

I want to change the viewport metatag for a single page on my website. I want the rest of the website to adhere to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But I want one particular page (id=7730) to adhere to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - I'm a backend/html/php beginner, so layman's terms are helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WordPress [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to accomplish this. Both `is_page()` and `is_singular()` should work, you just need to pass a slug, or in your case, an ID. Then we can use the `wp_head` hook to conditional add in the meta tag.

You can add the following function and hook into your `functions.php` file.

```
/**
 * Conditionally add metatag to specific page
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse359922_metatag_conditional() {

    if( is_page( 7730 ) ) {
        echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">';
    } else {
        echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">';
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse359922_metatag_conditional' );
```

On a side-note, your whole website *should* be mobile friendly otherwise it will get dinged on SEO by engines like Google and Bing.

Comment: Hi Howdy_McGee, thanks very much for your response. I've added this into header.php where the initial piece of code is, and this hasn't worked - it just shows the code in plain text at the top of the webpage. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to all this!

Comment: @ClearlyGeorge You would want to add the above code into your `functions.php` file. If you haven't already, you may want to create a child theme using the [Child Theme Configurator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/) so your changes do not get overwritten. Checkout the [WordPress Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for additional information on why this is important. If you find this answer solves your issue ensure that you click the checkmark to let others know your answre has been solved.